# CNN implementation low accuracy on MINST data

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras, cnn, vgg16

I'm trying to implement VGG11 (Model A of Table 1 from this [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.1556.pdf)) on the MINST dataset but I'm getting ~10% train & test accuracy (as bad as random guessing). I had to resize the MINST data from 28x28 to 32x32 to fit the CNN architecture. This is what I did:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten
from keras import optimizers, utils
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Preprocessing

x_size = 6000 # Changed to reduce training time 
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train_ = np.ndarray((x_size, 32, 32))
x_test_ = np.ndarray((x_test.shape[0], 32, 32))

# Resizing inputs to 32x32
for i in [0, x_size-1]:
    im = Image.fromarray(x_train[i], mode=None)
    im = im.resize((32, 32))
    x_train_[i] = np.array(im)
for i in [0,x_test.shape[0]-1]:
    im = Image.fromarray(x_test[i], mode=None)
    im = im.resize((32, 32))
    x_test_[i] = np.array(im)

x_train_ = x_train_.reshape(x_train_.shape[0], 32, 32, 1)
x_test_ = x_test_.reshape(x_test_.shape[0], 32, 32, 1)

y_train = utils.to_categorical(y_train,10)
y_test = utils.to_categorical(y_test,10)
y_train_ = y_train[:x_size]


# Model A (VGG11) of Table 1: ConvNet configurations from paper arXiv:1409.1556v6

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(32, 32, 1), data_format='channels_last'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

# Model compilation

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True, clipnorm=1.), metrics=['accuracy'])

# Model fitting

model.fit(x_train_, y_train_, epochs=1, batch_size=32)

# Model evaluation

score = model.evaluate(x_train_, y_train_)
print('Train loss after 1 epoch:', score[0])
print('Train accuracy after 1 epoch:', score[1])
```

I've tried normalizing the input, changing training sizes, increasing epochs, changing FC/filter size, and changing optimizers (and learning rate). Train accuracy is as low from both the evaluation report and TensorFlow's History report. I'm expecting >95% accuracy. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try normalizing the input images like: x_train /= 255 x_test /= 255

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding dropout to the network to avoid overfitting.
read the docs for more information
https://keras.io/layers/core/

and try these things as well

since the targets are integers,its better to use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` than `categorical_crossentropy` and optimizer as Adam

```
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and try by using `sigmoid` activation function for output layer

```
model.add(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Comment: I tried dropout to no avail. Also, I dont think sparse_categorical_crossentropy and sigmoid is the way to go as I have 10 classes.

Answer (score 0):

What did you increased the epochs to? You are trying to retrain VGG11 from scratch and it has over 30million parameters, which is expected to take a long time. Are you trying to use transfer learning, taking the pre-trained weights and freezing all the layers but the last one to use for your classification problem? In that case you are right to expect over %95 accuracy after a few epochs.

I don't know where to find the pre-trained VGG11 for TensorFlow by [here](https://www.kaggle.com/pytorch/vgg11) is the one for PyTorch.

Comment: I increased the epoch to 1000. However, my train loss and accuracy remained constant after the 5th epoch. I couldn't find a pre trained VGG11 model for my application as the original VGG11 works with 1000 classes while I'm using 10 classes for MINST.

Comment: You can still use the pre-trained model. What you need to the is called "Transfer Learning": you take a pre-trained model, freeze the weights all its layers except for the last layer. You just replace the last layer of 1000 classes with 10 classes of your own choice. It does not have to be your application directly. As long as it is trained on images it will should perform well. And with just one layer to trained, you can let it run for much longer.

Comment: That might work. Nonetheless, I think it'll be a great learning experience to know what went wrong with my code.

Comment: How long does it take to go through one epoch? If possible let it run overnight. Accuracy will probably improve but it will take time as it is starting from scratch. And how large is MNIST dataset you are working with? If it is the one with 60000 samples the network with over 30 million parameters is definitely too muchl.

Comment: I tried a VGG16 pre-trained model with parameter classes = 10. model.evaluate gives the same low 9.8% accuracy and 2.3 cross-entropy error. I suspect that something is wrong with the resize step.

Comment: Did you freeze the other parameters? That is odd. Here is a video clip from a fast.ai course where they mention some student use transfer learning for Devanagari text recognition and they seem to hit 99 percent accuracy. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ccMHJeQU4Qw&t=5m59s